# passing data to a specific label in another view controller, depending on the button pressed

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm just starting out with swift and decided to create a calorie counting app to test my skills in which I am using an Api to get the nutrition data.

Pressing the add breakfast/lunch/dinner segues to a search view controller from which I pass the calories back.

I am using protocol delegate design pattern. I wanted to know how I could set it up so that when I press the add breakfast button, only the breakfast calorie label is updated and when I press add lunch or dinner, their calorie labels are updated accordingly. any help would be greatly appreciated! I posted the codes of my logViewController and SearchViewController

```
import UIKit

protocol DataDelegate {
    func updateLogCalories(str: String?)
}

class SearchViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,CalorieManagerDelegate{
    var delagate: DataDelegate?
    @IBOutlet weak var searchTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var calorieLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var foodNameLabel: UILabel!
    var calorieManager = CalorieManager()
    var logCals : String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        calorieManager.delegate=self
        searchTF.delegate=self
    }
    
    @IBAction func searchPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        searchTF.endEditing(true)
        print(searchTF.text!)
    }
    
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delagate?.updateLogCalories(str: logCals)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    class LogViewController: UIViewController{
        var breakfastCal: String?
        @IBOutlet weak var breakfastLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var lunchLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var totalCaloriesLabel: UILabel!
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
        
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            let navController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let destController = navController.topViewController as! SearchViewController
            
            destController.delagate = self
        }
        
        @IBAction func addBreakfastPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        }
        
        @IBAction func addLunchPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        }
    }
    
    extension LogViewController: DataDelegate{
        func updateLogCalories(str: String?) {
            breakfastLabel.text = str
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do all of your buttons trigger the addButtonPressed action?

Answer (score 0):

If all of your buttons (breakfast, lunch, and dinner) trigger the addButtonPressed action, you need a way to tell which button was pressed, and a way to pass that information to the DataDelegate.

I suggest you put your buttons into an array:

```
@IBOutlet weak var breakfastButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var lunchButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var dinnerButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Populate our array of buttons so we can search for a button
    buttons = [breakfastButton, lunchButton, dinnerButton]
}
```

Then modify your DataDelegate protocol to include a meal enum:

```
enum Meal: Int {
   case breakfast = 0
   case lunch = 1
   case dinner = 2
}

protocol DataDelegate {
    func updateLogCalories(str: String?, forMeal meal: Meal)
}
```

And set up your DataDelegate to implement the new method:

```
class MyDataDelegate: DataDelegate {
    func updateLogCalories(str: String?, forMeal meal: Meal) {
        let str = str ?? ""
        print("updating calories with string \(str) for meal \(meal)")
    }
}
```

Now modify your addButtonPressed method so it searches the array to figure out which button was pressed.

```
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let index = buttons.firstIndex(of: sender),
           let meal = Meal(rawValue: index) {
             print("Button at index \(index) pressed")
             delegate.updateLogCalories(str: nil, forMeal: meal)
        } else {
            print("Can't find button or can't create enum.")
        }
    }
```